# how to do jest-dom test while component has props or callback function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I want to do unit test by using jest-dom.
I have a component which contains props and methods。
unit test is like this

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'
import MultiCheck,{Option} from "./MultiCheck";

describe('MultiCheck', () => {
  describe('initialize', () => {
    it('renders the label if label provided', () => {
         // TODO
        //TS2739: Type '{ handleItemClick: any; options: any; }' 
      // is missing the following properties from type 'Props': columns, values, selectedAll
        const wrapper = render(<MultiCheck handleItemClick={} options={}/>)
      
    });
  });
});
```

I don't know how to do jest-dom test?can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass **all** props that are used by the component. Easy way out can be:
Have something like below:

```
const defaultProps = {
   handleItemClick: // initial mock value,
   options: // initial mock value,
......... all props here
}
```

Then pass it to your component something like below:

```
const wrapper = render(<MultiCheck {...defaultProps}/>)
```